# What is the best way to differentiate between a cell phone device and a tablet in JS?

Tags: javascript, mobile

Our application needs to redirect all mobile users to our mobile page. However, we only want to re-direct cell phone users, not tablet users. I am looking for a best solution that does that in Javascript.

Any ideas? Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well since some phones now have the same screen size as a tablet its quite hard to differentiate but the way I do it with my size is to use a standard screen size and if people's devices are above or below it, it decides what site they browse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (screen.width <= 800) 
  {
      window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hints,

there are three ways:

1. User-agent strings
2. Capabilities (mostly the same for these devices)
3. Screen sizes (e.g for CSS media queries)
4. combination of the above